# висят delete в Git

Tags: git

При вводе git status вылезают куча deleted: folder/.....
При pull/push - не удаляются. Как их убрать, а то их ну очень много. Спасибо.

Comment: видимо Вы поудаляли каталоги вместо с файлами? попробуйте просто добавить эти папки (git add) и закоммитить.

Answer (score 0):

При удалении файлов с папками: git add --all ; commit -m 'deleted folder/file';
И теперь не отображаются в статусе.